# axis 1 and guice integration

Tags: java, guice, axis

Is there a way to integrate guice and axis 1? Or to attach custom factory class creating instances of web services? If not maybe there is a way to use existing class instance as axis web services?

Comment: I'm stuck with Axis1.x too, not Spring nor Guice

Comment: Well, you have to define custom interfaces and wrap it with your axis implementation. I don't think there is a Axis1 guice wrapper. Put some code example to point you to right path.